# Unable to read Pillar having array with dictionary structure using Jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to read an array of dictionary present in my salt pillar file inside my state sls file, but unable to read.

```
root@xxxxxxx:/srv/salt# salt-master --version
salt-master 3003.3
```

I am having pillar file as below:

Pillar File:

```
common:
  sysctl.net.core.netdev_max_backlog: 16384
  sysctl.net.core.optmem_max: 25165824
  sysctl.net.core.rmem_max: 33554432
  sysctl.net.core.somaxconn: 16384
deploy2:
  packages:
    - repo_name: xxxxxxxx
      tag: xxxxxx
      path: /tmp/sp_repo_1
    - repo_name: xxxxxx
      tag: sxxxxxx
      path: /tmp/sp_repo_2
```

My state file as below:

```
{% for package in salt.pillar.get('deploy2:packages') %}

print my data:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "echo {{ package.repo_name }}"

{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:test' failed: while constructing a mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 1
found conflicting ID 'print my data'
  in "<unicode string>", line 9, column 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of the states being run in context of an execution should be unique.

As you are iterating over an array of dictionaries having two elements, it creates two state IDs as `print my data`, which is not allowed. To avoid this, we need to use some element of the dict in the ID itself so that it is unique.

Example:

```
{% for package in salt.pillar.get('deploy2:packages') %}
print-my-{{ package.repo_name }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "echo {{ package.repo_name }}"
{% endfor %}
```

This will create 2 unique IDs - `print-my-xxxxxxxx` and `print-my-xxxxxx`. You could use `package.tag` or any such key which has unique values.